# Upload files to MVC and stream them to WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently trying to upload about 6 files to `ASP.NET MVC`. Once uploaded, I need to stream them to `WCF`, have `WCF` write them to the file system.

I also need a way to handle the file size. All files are going to be images and they could be up too 100MB and I don't want the page to timeout.

Could someone point me in the right direction of where to go or how to get started.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FileUpload file)
    {
        foreach (string upload in Request.Files)
        {                
            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "uploads/";
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[upload].FileName);
            Request.Files[upload].SaveAs(Path.Combine(path, filename));
        }
        TempData["Status"] = "Your files were successfully upload.";
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Employees");
    }
```

Later I'll add something to validate if the files are actually there or not. Thanks in advance!

### Update

After messing around a little bit, here is what I've come up with

```
foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                FileUploadStream uploadedFile = null;

                uploadedFile.FileName = file.FileName;
                uploadedFile.StreamData = file.InputStream;
                uploadedFile.FileSize = file.ContentLength;

                BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
                byte[] binData = b.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);

                using (Proxy<IFileUpload> Proxy = new Proxy<IFileUpload>())
                {
                    uploadedFile = Proxy.Channel.SaveFiles(uploadedFile.FileName, binData);
                    Proxy.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["Error"] = "Didn't work :(";
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Employees");
            }
        }

        TempData["Status"] = "Holy crap, it worked :)";
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Employees");
```

However when the code executes, the `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files` is null. Here is a look at my view:

```
    @model Common.Contracts.DataContracts.FileUploadStream

    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Upload Tool";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>IFileUpload</legend>
            PHOTO <input type="file" name="signUpload" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Upload Files" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `ContentLength`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.Request.Files.Count; i++)
{
   var file = this.Request.Files[i];

   //
   // ContentLength comes in bytes, you must convert it to MB and then
   // compare with 100 MB
   //
   if(file.ContentLength / 1024 / 1024 > 100)
   {
      TempData["Status"] += file.FileName + " has It size greater than 100MB";
   }
   else
   {
     string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "uploads/";
     string filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
     file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(path, filename));
   }
}
```